# ¿Cómo escribir en celdas excel referencias en lugar de valores con una macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Quiero utilizar la referencia de celdas (como un puntero en C++) y no sus valores absolutos en VBA en celdas que varían en función de una otra valor.

He hecho lo siguiente con `Cells(x,y).Value` pero me da la valor absoluto cuando quiero el equivalente de `=$A$1$` por ejemplo.

```
Cells(8 + i, 6 + nbrVille).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value * Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, 4 + j_Distances).Value

i = 0
For i_Distancia = 1 To nbrSitio
    For j_Distancia = 1 To nbrCiudad
        Cells(8 + i, 7 + nbrCiudad).Value = ">="
        Cells(8 + i, 8 + nbrCiudad).Value = Sheets("Distancia").Cells(i_Distancia, j_Distancia ).Value - 2
        Cells(8 + i, 6 + nbrCiudad).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value * Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, 4 + j_Distancia).Value
        i = i + 1

    Next j_Distancia
Next i_Distancia
```

Eso es necesario por hacer restricciones dinámicas para un solver.

Por lo momento la macro me da :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quiero :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sustituye esto

```
Cells(8 + i, 6 + nbrCiudad).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value
                                  * Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, 4 + j_Distancia).Value
```

Por esto

```
Cells(8 + i, 6 + nbrCiudad).Formula = "=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Address &
                                      "*" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, 4 + j_Distancia).Address
```